# Video streaming from Firebase made fast

Tags: ios, firebase, swift3, streaming, video-streaming

Okay so I have a bunch of videos in my firebase server. While on the app they can be retrieved and streamed in the app. I'm having a huge issue though,

Say the video is 2 minutes, it'll buffer at 1 minute in intervals of 5 seconds and just play terribly. I've compressed the videos down to about 14mb per minute. However buffering still seems to be a problem.

I just set up a regular AVPlayer

```
let url = URL(string: "myurl")
Player = AVPlayer(URL: URL)
// Add the player layer
Player.play()
```

Bam the video plays perfectly but then starts buffering insanely at a minute.

So I was wondering is there a method to stream videos faster and avoid constant buffering. I've heard of google platforms such as Anvanto. Other ones such as Zencoder or Bitmovin.

I'm not too familiar with these, if anyone can inform me on what to use to solve my issue 
or what route to take, that'd be great!

Comment: Could it be a scaling issue? Have you noticed the max bandwidth firebase allows and it suits your needs? Then you could start looking at other solutions

Comment: So would you recommend I contact firebase, ask about the bandwidth and see where to go from there?

Comment: you should have an idea of the plan you are using in firebase. The free plan has some extreme limitations. What kind of product you are using on their cloud?  if you are streaming fairly 1080p videos, for a single app it should not buffer. I would recommend contacting their support if you have a need to use firebase. There are better solutions out there for video streaming.

Comment: What are better solutions for video streaming that you recommend?

Comment: If the pricing suits you, I would suggest going for google cloud platform https://cloud.google.com/solutions/media/architecture/live-streaming/ . They even have a use case and architecture... I would also suggest looking at AWS solutions for it.